# Mark a specific level in contour map

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

Can anyone give me an example of how to mark a specific level in a contour map?
I would like to mark the level which is the black line in this plot:

[image: Contour map in which I want to mark a level]

I am using the following code:

```
plt.figure()

CS = plt.contour(X, Y,log_mu,levels = [np.log10(5e-8),np.log10(9e-5)])
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y,log_mu)
CB = plt.colorbar(CS, shrink=0.8, extend='both')

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

And the data for this specific plot can be obtained here [dpaste data for contour plot](http://dpaste.com/0J3VJST)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html) from the matplotlib gallery for contour plot functionality.  By modifying the levels in your script, as well as changing some of the references, leads to :

```
plt.figure()

CS = plt.contour(X, Y,log_mu,levels = [-7,-8],
                 colors=('k',),linestyles=('-',),linewidths=(2,))
CSF = plt.contourf(X, Y,log_mu)
plt.clabel(CS, fmt = '%2.1d', colors = 'k', fontsize=14) #contour line labels
CB = plt.colorbar(CSF, shrink=0.8, extend='both')

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image]